# How to adjust divs height according the size of one of them and covering 100%?

Tags: html, css

I have one main div covering the 100% of the available space in webpage, and it contains three others divs, like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"/>
    <div id="content"/>
    <div id="footer"/>
</div>
```

I need two of them (the yellow ones) to be resizable, because their content is dynamic and sometimes need more than a single line of text. So, what I need is they cover the 20% of the available space but if they need more to resize and make the center div smaller. What should I read about? I don't find the keywords to google it. Thanks a lot!
[This is a "not-working demo"](http://jsfiddle.net/6d3e12nn/1/) haha:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe these answers are understanding the question.

If I get you correctly, you want to have the top and bottom be some minimum height (say 20% each), and the center fill the rest.

In that case you will have to use JavaScript. Find the height of `window` and set top and bot to have a min-height. This will allow them to scale. From there you will get the height of the head and the foot, subtract them from the height of `window`, and set the content area to be that height.

I would write you out an example but it sounds like you want to do it yourself, which I commend.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS min-height property on the header and footer divs, and remove the height property from the content div.

```
#header, #footer {
   min-height: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's great! But if you resize the window you'll see that the three divs are not covering the 100% (you'll see the red area) http://jsfiddle.net/6d3e12nn/3/